# Adding new instance to instance group?

Tags: google-compute-engine

So I'm running a LAMP stack on Google Compute Engine and I'm new to it so a bit confused.

The current instance CPU utilisation is almost always maxed out and I'd like to add another one, how do I do that?

It seems I have to create a new instance with whatever server I decide and then add it to the instance group there but the instance I created doesn't show in the dropdown that says add an instance below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your instance group is located in `europe-west1-b`, the new instance which you wish to add to this group has to be created in the same zone, then it'll be appeared in the `Add an instance` drop-down menu.